# rumbling of the engine during acceleration after a rainy day

Tags: engine, cel, intermittent-problems

After it rained all day, my 2003 Ford Escape seemed to rumble
a bit, and the check engine light came on. When I was at a stop light, the check engine light went off, but when I accelerated the check engine light came back on. The next day, after being in the garage all night the car worked fine.

Comment: Great question! I used to have a similar problem on my 1989 Opel Vectra but without check engine light, and the problem vanished after reaching a certain RPM. I suspected the distributor cap (plugs and wires had been replaced) but never really replaced the distributor cap before I had to get rid of the car due to too many bigger problems. Does your car have one ignition coil per plug directly on top of the plug, or one common ignition coil? I suspect the more modern one coil per plug design should eliminate the problem.

Comment: not 100% positive, but I think the V6 version is coil on plug and the I4 is one big coil.  I don't think it has a distributor.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is your ignition system (rotor/distributor/wires/plugs) the rain causes the spark to jump to places it shouldn't